# Как соединить метки прямыми линиями?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Есть массив координат меток, как можно соединить все метки прямыми линиями?
Так же я могу перетаскивать метки по карте (**draggable: true**), необходимо, чтобы во время перетаскивания, линия соединяющая метки перерисовывалась.
Пример с перетаскиванием: https://monosnap.com/file/PIAX0HuKyo2yN1s1M6SwuO66YuKMmo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так:

```
var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(myMap.getCenter(), {}, {
  draggable: true
});

var myPlacemark2 = new ymaps.Placemark([55.661574, 37.573856], {}, {
  draggable: true
});

myMap.geoObjects
  .add(myPlacemark)
  .add(myPlacemark2);
var myPolyline = new ymaps.Polyline([
// Указываем координаты вершин ломаной.
  myPlacemark.geometry.getCoordinates(),
  myPlacemark2.geometry.getCoordinates()
]);

// Добавляем линии на карту.
myMap.geoObjects.add(myPolyline);
myPlacemark.geometry.events.add('change', function(e) {
  var newCoords = e.get('newCoordinates');
  myPolyline.geometry.set(0, newCoords);
});
myPlacemark2.geometry.events.add('change', function(e) {
  var newCoords = e.get('newCoordinates');
  myPolyline.geometry.set(1, newCoords);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fc9vy4br/